# Routing in the Zend Framework 2

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

It's not long since I'm using Zend Framework 2 and I'm trying to write a route for a product that have the rule something like that:

> /[slug]-test[ID][av|ai|cv|ci|svb|sib|svc|sic|svi|sii|tv|ti]

An exemple for this rule would look like this:

> /freezer-in-good-shape-test12345cv

I try to this with REGEX:

```
'details' => array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Regex',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '(?<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-test(?<id>[0-9]+)(?<sufix>(av|ai|cv|ci|svb|sib|svc|sic|svi|sii|tv|ti))',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                    'controller' => 'List',
                    'action' => 'details',
                ),
                'spec' => '%slug%-test%id%%sufix%',
            )
        ),
```

and with SEGMENT too:

```
'details' => array(
            'type' => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/:slug-test:id:sufix',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                    'controller' => 'List',
                    'action' => 'details',
                )
                'constraints' => array(
                    'slug' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id' => '[0-9]*',
                    'sufix' => '[av|ai|cv|ci|svb|sib|svc|sic|svi|sii|tv|ti]'
                )
            )
        ),
```

but it's not working. Can anyone tell what is that i'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I’d go with `Segment` here. The only issue I’ve noticed in your route config is the `sufix` constraint: instead of `[av|ai|…]` you should type `(av|ai|…)`.

Answer (score 0):

please try with this-

```
'details' => array(
            'type' => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/:slug[-test]:id:sufix',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                    'controller' => 'List',
                    'action' => 'details',
                )
                'constraints' => array(
                    'slug' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id' => '[0-9]*',
                    'sufix' => '[av|ai|cv|ci|svb|sib|svc|sic|svi|sii|tv|ti]'
                )
            )
        ),
```

on this line `'route' => '/:slug-test:id:sufix',`

you had the issues, as it considers "slug-test" as single variable.
so for this you should separate "-test" with "slug" variable.

`'route' => '/:slug[-test]:id:sufix',`